# r - roxygen documentation - escape quotation marks on separate lines

Tags: r, roxygen2, quotation-marks

I am working on documentation for a function in my package. Below is the section of the help file that throws errors with `roxygen2`:

```
#' Solve the Colebrook-White equation to obtain the Darcy-Weisbach friction factor
#'
#' This function \"provides the fast, accurate, and robust computation of the
#' Colebrook-White equation\" to determine the \"Darcy-Weisbach friction factor
#' F\". This method is \"more efficient than the solution of the Colebrook
#' equation via the Lambert W-function, or the simple approximations.\" The
#' solution is accurate to \"around machine precision for all R > 3 and for all
#' 0 <= K, i.e. for all values of physical interest.\" Source: Clamond
```

Since I have quotation marks on separate lines, how do I escape the unclosed quotation marks on each line?

Thank you.